# Commerce Kickstart 2 - Disable ajax in seach products backend

Tags: commerce, search

How can I disable ajax in admin/commerce/products (Commerce Kickstart 2 menu)? I've searched  in Search API settings but found nothing.

Edit: I found that the View Commerce Backoffice: Products (Content) control the search of products in admin/commerce/products. In section Advanced > OTHER there is field Use AJAX. You can set to `Yes` or `No` this field. But even if you set to `No`, when you search for a product the query is made before you press Enter, what is exactly my client want.

So the question persists, is there a way to change this behavior, to be able to search only when you press Enter?

Comment: It's a View isn't it? Try disabling AJAX in the View edit form?

Comment: Thanks @Clive. I disabled AJAX in Advanced/OTHER/Use Ajax option in the View. Now when searching, the animated blue clock doesn't appear but the page keep refresh as I insert some letters in the text box. Is there other option to be changed?

Answer (score 1):

You can install (if it's not installed yet) Better Exposed Filters. If you edit the View in admin/commerce/products/list (or any of them) and you select BEF for displaying your exposed filters (using defaults) then the autosubmit feature will no longer work.

On the other hand, see https://www.drupal.org/node/1735254 for an explanation on how to disable the autosubmit feature. It's just adding a CSS class to your filter. You have to find out how to add classes to exposed filters in Views, though. Some dirty jQuery can help, I guess.